# How can I create secrets for use with the Secrets API auth-source?

Tags: security, authinfo

Trying to create new secrets in the GNOME keyring via `auth-source` results in

> The Secrets API auth-source backend doesn’t support creation yet

How can I manually create this secret?

Comment: This is a known restriction, see https://debbugs.gnu.org/30246 . It's on my todo list, with slow progress.

Comment: I saw that! This is simply a stop gap measure in the meantime that I've had to use a couple of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is confirm which fields need to be included in the secret. Frequently this includes `host` and `user`. For `smtp`, this also includes `port`. You can find this information by looking for an `auth-source-search` call (or using `edebug` to pause execution on it).

If all you need is `host` and `user`, you can use a graphical client like Seahorse if you have it already. Otherwise, you can manually create the secret using Python and [`secretstorage`](https://secretstorage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as follows:

```py
import secretstorage
bus = secretstorage.dbus_init()
collection = secretstorage.get_default_collection(bus)
fields = {'field1': 'field1-value', 'field2': 'field2-value'}
secret = input('Enter secret followed by RET: ')
collection.create_item("Secret name", fields, secret)
```